# Why is it an error to const-qualify a parameter pack of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, variadic-functions

When implementing a function which accepts a parameter pack of pointers to `Ts...`, why can't I `const`-qualify the pointers, as is possible with regular parameters?

I get a mismatching signature error on latest GCC and Clang, and I don't see why, since the pointers being `const` is just an implementation detail (hence it being legal for regular parameters).

```
template<typename... Ts>
class C
{
    void f(int*);
    void g(Ts*...);
};

template<typename... Ts>
void C<Ts...>::f(int* const) {} // Legal

template<typename... Ts>
void C<Ts...>::g(Ts* const...) {} // Compiler error
```

I am getting this error:

```
prog.cc:12:16: error: out-of-line definition of 'g' does not match any declaration in 'C<Ts...>'
void C<Ts...>::g(Ts* const...) {}
               ^
1 error generated.
```

You can also see the code and error [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HZBXjIoxC0fVNFi3).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm going to chalk it up to a pair of compiler bugs (tested Clang and GCC). It's a bold assertion, I know, but [[dcl.fct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5) says, emphasis mine:

> A single name can be used for several different functions in a single
>   scope; this is function overloading. All declarations for a function
>   shall agree exactly in both the return type and the
>   parameter-type-list. The type of a function is determined using the
>   following rules. **The type of each parameter (including function
>   parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and
>   declarator.** After determining the type of each parameter, any
>   parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be
>   “pointer to T”. **After producing the list of parameter types, any
>   top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when
>   forming the function type.** **The resulting list of transformed parameter
>   types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis or a function
>   parameter pack is the function's parameter-type-list.** [ Note: This
>   transformation does not affect the types of the parameters. For
>   example, int(*)(const int p, decltype(p)*) and int(*)(int, const int*)
>   are identical types.  — end note ]

Which reads to me, quite clearly, that the declarations of both members (`f` *and* `g`) match the out-of-class definitions, making your program valid. So Clang and GCC should accept it.

Comment: This is weird: clang accepts two definitions of `g`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/y6GAGVXg00jrDnn4

Comment: @YSC - Seems like Clang encodes more data in the function signature than it should.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - please see my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66698177/751579) for an update 3 years later - just curious if you have any further analysis?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - plus, the standard paragraph you quoted indicates the const qualifier is simply _dropped_.  Does this mean you can't take a variadic templates parameter pack arg and use it to declare (say, in a method of the template class) a generic method taking that same parameter pack except everything is in fact const-qualified?

Comment: (Never mind my last question: That does in fact work (a (nongeneric) method taking that same parameter pack except everything is in fact const-qualified)).

Comment: @davidbak - I don't really have much of a further analysis. The same exact paragraph exists in the latest standard. According to your answer Clang and GCC still have a bug. But given this is a somewhat atypical use of function parameter packs, I can see why it wasn't addressed. It's almost always a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

3 years later ... FYI ...

MSVC 19.28.29337 (with Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.5) compiles and runs the following with `/W4 /Wx`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
class C
{
public:
    void f(int*);
    void g(Ts*...);
};

template<typename... Ts>
void C<Ts...>::f(int* const pi) {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "f " << *pi << endl;
}

template<typename... Ts>
void C<Ts...>::g(Ts* const... tsargs) {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "g ";
    (cout << ... << *tsargs);
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    C<int, float, char> cifc;

    int* pi = new int{ 5 };
    cifc.f(pi);

    float* pf = new float{ 1.0f };
    char* pc = new char{ 'a' };
    cifc.g(pi, pf, pc);
}
```

But neither GCC HEAD 11.0.1 20210 nor Clang HEAD 13.0.0 does, with either C++17 nor C++2a.

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aeP3s6cDjjckFGOO)